# ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: num.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript

New to coding and new to the site.

I am trying to build a calculator from a YouTube video and I was following the steps until I came across this error in the console.log: Uncaught TypeError: num.replace is not a function.

- I've copied and pasted the actual JS from github into my JS file and it works perfectly.
- I've copied and pasted my code and the JS from github into excel and compared side by side and everything lined up.
- I've copied and pasted my code and the JS from github into a text comparison site and compared side by side and everything lined up.

Not sure what else to do or why I am getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated by this noob!

My code is as follows:

```
function getHistory(){
    return document.getElementById("history-value").innerText;
}
function printHistory(num){
    document.getElementById("history-value").innerText=num;
}
function getOutput(){
    return document.getElementById("output-value").innerText;
}
function printOutput(num){
    if(num==""){
        document.getElementById("output-value").innerText=num;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("output-value").innerText=getFormattedNumber(num);
}
    }
function getFormattedNumber(num){
    if(num=="-"){
        return "";
    }
    let n = Number(num);
    let value = n.toLocaleString("en");
    return value;
}
function reverseNumberFormat(num){
    return Number(num.replace(/,/g,''));
}
let operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
for(let i=0;i<operator.length;i++){
    operator[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(this.id=="clear"){
            printHistory("");
            printOutput("");
        }
        else if(this.id=="backspace"){
            let output=reverseNumberFormat(getOutput).toString();
            if(output){
                output= output.substr(0,output.length-1);
                printOutput(output);
            }
        }
    });
}

let number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (let i=0; i< number.length;i++){
    number[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        let output=reverseNumberFormat(getOutput());
        if(output!=NaN){
            output=output+this.id;
            printOutput(output);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `let output=reverseNumberFormat(getOutput).toString();` <= potential typo with not putting the `()` on `getOutput()`

Comment: If `num` is a number, you should use `num.toString().replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

The value being passed may not be a string you should do as follows

```
function reverseNumberFormat(num){
    return Number(num.toString().replace(/,/g,''));
}
```

Thats why the error is a TypeError

Comment: I used the num.toString().replace, but not I am getting "NaN" when I click any of the operator buttons

Comment: what are some example values being passed in?

Comment: I actually made a small typo remove the ' '  from around the /,/g that shouldn't have been there

Comment: For example, I click 8 on the calculator and 8 appears in the history window, then I click "+" or "*" on the calculator and the "+" or "*" does not appear next to the 8 as it should, and I get the error above in the console.log.

Comment: So it happens only when adding a non numeric value? cause you are casting the replaced values to a Number so that might explain the NaN

Comment: So one thing I failed to mention was that in the video the developer uses var, and I was under the impression that using var was outdated so I switched to let. Could this be a potential issue?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. From looking at the code I think is cause of the cast on the return your going to end up trying to cast a + or - to a Number and that won't work